# pointer parameter vs pointer return value

Tags: python, c++, pointers, parameter-passing, return-value

When I was embedding some python code into my C++ program and trying to import a python module and get a pointer to it, I here have two options:

Passing an empty pointer as an argument:

```
void importPyModule(PyObject * modPtr, const char *modName){
    modPtr = PyImport_ImportModule(modName);

    if(modPtr == nullptr){
        std::cout << "python module: " << modName << " import failed\npython message: ";
        PyErr_Print();
        std::exit(1);
    }
}
```

Or returning a pointer:

```
PyObject *importPyModule(const char *modName){
    PyObject *modPtr = PyImport_ImportModule(modName);

    if(modPtr == nullptr){
        std::cout << "python module: " << modName << " import failed\npython message: ";
        PyErr_Print();
        std::exit(1);
    }
}
```

For completeness, This is where I am calling my function:

```
#include "Python.h"
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main(){

    initPython(); // initialize the interpreter and set appropriate paths
    PyObject *aws_tools, *boto, *imp, *sdb;

    // Option 1: return pointer
    aws_tools = importPyModule("aws_tools");
    // Or option 2: pass a pointer
    importPyModule(aws_tools, "aws_tools");

    /* Some other code */

    return 0;
}
```

When I pass the pointer as an argument, I get a pointer that points to:

```
<unknown at [some address]>
```

But when I the pointer a return value from the function, I get:

```
<module at [some address]>
```

The pointer to module will work properly while the pointer to unknown will crash the program.

My question is: Are there better ways of doing this job (than using pointers?)

What is causing the difference in behavior here?

I am using g++ with c++11 standard and python2.6

Comment: For option 1 you would need to pass the pointer by reference. Otherwise you are assigning to a copy which doesn't affect the given pointer.

Comment: Gosh I feel dumb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your parameter example it's a local variable so the value in the calling function doesn't  change.

If you make the parameter example take a pointer-to-pointer and fix the rest accordingly the calling function's value would then be changed and it would work.